# Google Bigquery table decorator with where clause

Tags: google-bigquery

it's said that table decorator is more cost-effective, so I did my testing:

select count(distinct ID) from [myDataSet.myTable@-86400000--30000]

it shows only 15.6 GB data will be scaned 
Valid: This query will process 15.6 GB when run.

when I add a where clause, it shows it will process over double data size:

select count(distinct ID) from [myDataSet.myTable@-86400000--30000] where col='something'
Valid: This query will process 34.0 GB when run.***

why there is a difference? how can I avoid that?

Answer (score 4):

If col is NOT "distinct ID", then it's normal.

Big Query "processed size" depends on the number of COLUMNS it needs to scan. If you put col on top of distinctID in your return, then it will need to read both. Would make sense the size doubles, no?

Try checking how much data `select distinctID, col from [myDataSet.myTable@-86400000--30000]`. I have a feeling it'll be the same :)